# How to list all subcategories from all categories but not from a certain category

Tags: categories

I know how to list all subcategories from a certain category, but don't know how to list all subcategories from all categories.

For example, here is category:

```
Category 1
    -Child Category1
    -Child Category2
Category 2
    -Child Category3
    -Child Category4
Category 3
    -Child Category5
    -Child Category6
```

The list i want is :

```
-Child Category1
-Child Category2
-Child Category3
-Child Category4
-Child Category5
-Child Category6
```

This is code i have now

```
<?php wp_list_categories( array(
    'orderby'=> 'id',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'show_count' => false,
    'use_desc_for_title' => false,
     'title_li' => '',
) ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, according to official documentation, you should pass depth argument inside your function.

As it's written [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/)

Try this:

```
  <?php wp_list_categories( array(
    'orderby'=> 'id',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'show_count' => false,
    'use_desc_for_title' => false,
    'title_li' => '',
    'depth; => 1
   ) ); ?>
```